# Undefined member variable

Tags: php, oop

I've created following class:

```
class NotFoundException extends Exception {}
class Foo{
    private $path;
    private $array;

    public static function load($name) {
        try {
            return new Foo($name);
        } catch (NotFoundException $unfe) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function __construct($name){
        if (true){
            $this->$path = 'public_html/'.$name.'/';
            $this->$array= array('1','2','3');
        }
        else
            throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    public function getArray(){
        return $this->$array;
    }
}
$foo = Foo::load('first');
print_r($foo->getArray());
```

When I run my code, I get
**NOTICE** Undefined variable: *path on line number 18*
**FATAL ERROR** Uncaught Error: *Cannot access empty property*

I have no idea what is causing the problem.

Comment: When setting or getting properties, don't use the dollar sign. Use `$this->path` instead of `$this->$path`

Comment: @rickdenhaan oh damn thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access your [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) like `$this->path` and `$this->array` without prepending the `$`.

You could update your code to:

```
class NotFoundException extends Exception {}
class Foo{
    private $path;
    private $array;

    public static function load($name) {
        try {
            return new Foo($name);
        } catch (NotFoundException $unfe) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function __construct($name){
        if (true){
            $this->path = 'public_html/'.$name.'/';
            $this->array= array('1','2','3');
        }
        else
            throw new NotFoundException();
    }

    public function getArray(){
        return $this->array;
    }
}
$foo = Foo::load('first');
print_r($foo->getArray());
```